# Having issues achieving a font blur with CSS

Tags: css

anyone have any insight in how to achieve a font blur with this level of intensity?

[image]

Comment: googling 'css font blur' yielded [this](http://motyar.blogspot.mx/2010/04/blur-effect-with-css-and-jquery.html), [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/blurry-text/) and [this](http://css-tricks.com/fun-with-blurred-text/) ... Google is your friend in these situations, take a chill pill and try again.

Comment: I cannot get enough grain out of the blur, I tried two of those links earlier :*(

Comment: If you're looking for grainy blur you'll have to go with images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this link: http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/04/blur-effect-with-css-and-jquery.html

You are basically looking for

```
color: transparent;   
text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #FF33FF;
```

Comment: Thanks guys going to work on, the next item on the list is to take two of the same headings make one really blurry and one not and stack them, just have to figure out how to do that and center them haha

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/vMna4/1/